# Clipboard that waits for the user to copy something again before it does the next C#

Tags: c#, while-loop, md5, clipboard

I want to make the following but i don't know how to start to do this what i want is.

**1.**  checks if md5 was copied

**2.**  then clears the clipboard

**3.** loop that  checks if the clipboard is still empty, and after that the notification copy what you want to hash to md5

**4.** code that does the hash after the clipboard is non-empty, and after all show a notification of the md5 hash what was copied.

this is my code for now

```
        switch ((clipboardText))
        {
            case "md5":
                ShowNotification("MD5 HASHER", "Copy what you want to hash to md5");
                {
                    ClearClipboard();
                    string input = GetTextClipboard();
                    // step 1, calculate MD5 hash from input
                    MD5 md5 = MD5.Create();
                    byte[] inputBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input);
                    byte[] hash = md5.ComputeHash(inputBytes);
                    // step 2, convert byte array to hex string
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    for (int i = 0; i < hash.Length; i++)
                    {
                        sb.Append(hash[i].ToString("X2"));
                    }
                    ShowNotification("md5 hash", sb.ToString());
                }
                break;
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

To checks the value of clipboard  call the method:

```
 public static string GetTextClipboard()
    {
        string txtReturn = null;
        Thread staThread = new Thread(
            delegate ()
            {
                try
                {
                    txtReturn = Clipboard.GetText();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }
            });
        staThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        staThread.Start();
        staThread.Join();
        return txtReturn;
    }
```

to Clear clipboard :

```
public static void ClearClipboard()
        {
            Thread staThread = new Thread(
                delegate ()
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Clipboard.Clear();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                    }
                });
            staThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            staThread.Start();
            staThread.Join();
        }
```

to Test it:

```
 while (true)
            {
                clipboardText = GetTextClipboard();
                switch ((clipboardText))
                {
                    case "md5":
                        ShowNotification("MD5 HASHER", "Copy what you want to hash to md5");
                        {
                            string source = GetTextClipboard();
                            using (MD5 md5Hash = MD5.Create())
                            {
                                string hash = GetMd5Hash(md5Hash, source);
                                ShowNotification("", "The MD5 hash is" + hash + ".");
                                ShowNotification("", "Verifying the hash...");
                                if (VerifyMd5Hash(md5Hash, source, hash))
                                {
                                    ShowNotification("", "The hashes are the same.");
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    ShowNotification("", "The hashes are not same.");
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        break;

                }
Thread.Sleep (2000); 
            }
```

Comment: yes that what im looking for how can i do the following steps in my question with your code?

Comment: if you call string s = GetTextClipboard();, have the value of  md5 was copied , and if you call ClearClipboard();  then clears the clipboard

Comment: and you can put all calls in a loop while (true)  {...}

Comment: can you show how i can do i loop while true with that?

Comment: I have modified the sample code in the answer, the last code, you have to add the call to ClearClipboard

Comment: One issue in my code now is i have multiple switch statements with clipboardText that are unreachable now how to fix that?

Comment: Remplace all with GetTextClipboard()

Comment: but the windows notifications returns slower when i did that

Comment: in this case you have to see using a timer to improve your code, as a quick solution adds Thread.Sleep (2000); after switch

Comment: can you show with switch name in your answer i can't get it done

Comment: I have modified the code but I do not understand the negative vote?

Comment: Because when i copy md5 hash it is still giving the hash of md5